# Dimensionality reduction using stationary wavelet transform

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, wavelet-transform

How can I reduce the dimension by using  2D [stationary wavelet transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_wavelet_transform)?

Comment: By keeping only a subset of the coefficients? However, the SWT is highly redundant. Consider using the discrete wavelet transform (DWT) instead.

Comment: @DaBler  could you please elaborate more?

Comment: You can keep only about 1–10% of the most significant coefficients to reduce the dimensionality (e.g., by thresholding of the coefficients, keeping only coarse resolutions, or applying some aggregating functions).